# How to securely get time delta between form load and form submit?

Tags: django

In Django, I have a view with the following method:

```
def get(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        # ... Process a filled form
    else:
        # ... Render a blank form
```

Tracking the epoch delta between when a form is rendered and returned is crucial to my application. In prototyping, I just used a hidden field to store the epoch of the render, but this is not secure (users can still edit a hidden field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        # ... Process a filled form
        render_epoch = request.session['render_epoch']
        submit_epoch = time.time()
    else:
        # ... Render a blank form
        request.session['render_epoch'] = time.time()
```

However, this solution updates the epoch when a user "backs" into a cached form.